# How does one deploy Gnosis safe on a custom subnet EVM

Tags: contract-deployment, contract-invocation

I am currently creating documentation for my organization regarding deploying a gnosis-safe on a custom EVM.

I'm having difficulty with interacting with the safe once it's deployed and would like some clarification on what the process is for deploying a safe, creating a txn, and mistakes to avoid during this process.

How does one deploy a safe and interact with it using hardhat?

Answer (score 0):

Deploying Gnosis Safe is not different from deploying any other smart contract.

- Make sure your Solidity smart contract programming skills are on a sufficient level before attempting to deal with production smart contracts
- [Follow the contract deployment instructions in Gnosis Safe repository](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts).

Comment: Thank you
More specifically my questions are: 

- when using `GnosisSafeProxyFactory.sol` to call `createProxy(address singleton, bytes memory data)` , is `singleton` the address of the initially deployed `gnosisSafeL2`?
how does one define `data`?


- when using `GnosisSafeProxyFactory.sol` to call `deployProxyWithNonce(address _singleton, bytes memory initializer, uint256 saltNonce)` , 
- how does one create the `initializer` and `salt` data?

- What is the best way to invoke a contract using hardhat?

- what is the best way to propose a txn and what are the steps?

Comment: This discussion is too technical to be had in the unreadable comment field. I suggest you go to Gnosis Safe Discord chat for support.